# Gmail OpenID user not recognized

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, dotnetopenauth, google-openid

I’ve setup OpenID in my MVC3 application and I am using a gmail login.  See my authentication form below.  I am implementing the code in http://weblogs.asp.net/haithamkhedre/archive/2011/03/13/openid-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc3-dotnetopenauth-and-openid-selector.aspx

When running locally with IIS express everything works fine and I get to the else statement and the buttonGreen code.  Once I deploy it on the web it trips on the “if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.UserName))” and I end up in the “New User, Register” code.  The model.OpenID is displayed.
The code works online with MyOpenId (which I’ve abandoned due to other problems).

The membership database has been rolled into the main database and users are created locally through the OpenID login, assigned to roles and then the database is pushed to the web.  I’m using the latest DotANetOpenAuth as of two weeks ago.  I’m using DotANetOpenAuth.Core, DotANetOpenAuth.OpenId and DotANetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyParty.

```
<form action="Authenticate?ReturnUrl=@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"])" method="post" id="openid_form">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="verify" />
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login using OpenID</legend>
        <div class="openid_choice">
            <p> Please click your account provider:</p>
            <div id="openid_btns"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="openid_input_area">
            @Html.TextBox("openid_identifier")
            <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
        </div>
        <noscript>
            <p>
                OpenID is service that allows you to log-on to many different websites using a single
                indentity. Find out <a href="http://openid.net/what/">more about OpenID</a> and
                <a href="http://openid.net/get/">how to get an OpenID enabled account</a>.</p>
        </noscript>
        <div>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.UserName))
                {
                  <div class="editor-label">
                      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OpenID)
                  </div>
                  <div class="editor-field">
                      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OpenID)
                  </div>
                  <p class="button">
                      @Html.ActionLink("New User, Register", "Register", new { OpenID = Model.OpenID })
                  </p>
                }
                else
                {
                //user exist 
                  <p class="buttonGreen">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "TalPro")">Welcome @Model.UserName, Continue... </a>
                  </p>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</form>
```

Here's the javascript: openid-jquery.js

```
/*
    Simple OpenID Plugin
    http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/

    This code is licensed under the New BSD License.
*/
var providers;
var openid;

(function ($) {
openid = {
    version : '1.3', // version constant
    demo : false,
    demo_text : null,
    cookie_expires : 6 * 30, // 6 months.
    cookie_name : 'openid_provider',
    cookie_path : '/',

    img_path : '../Content/themes/base/images/',
    locale : 'en', // is set in openid-<locale>.js
    sprite : 'en', // usually equals to locale, is set in
    // openid-<locale>.js
    signin_text : 'Sign-In', // text on submit button on the form
    all_small : false, // output large providers w/ small icons
    no_sprite : false, // don't use sprite image
    image_title : '{provider}', // for image title

    input_id : null,
    provider_url : null,
    provider_id : null,

    /**
     * Class constructor
     * 
     * @return {Void}
     */
    init : function(input_id) {
        providers = $.extend({}, providers_large);
        var openid_btns = $('#openid_btns');
        this.input_id = input_id;
        $('#openid_choice').show();
        $('#openid_input_area').empty();
        var i = 0;
        // add box for each provider
        for (id in providers_large) {
            box = this.getBoxHTML(id, providers_large[id], (this.all_small ? 'small' : 'large'), i++);
            openid_btns.append(box);
        }
        $('#openid_form').submit(this.submit);
        var box_id = this.readCookie();
        if (box_id) {
            this.signin(box_id, true);
        }
    },

    /**
     * @return {String}
     */
    getBoxHTML : function(box_id, provider, box_size, index) {
        if (this.no_sprite) {
            var image_ext = box_size == 'small' ? '.ico.gif' : '.gif';
            return '<a title="' + this.image_title.replace('{provider}', provider["name"]) + '" href="javascript:openid.signin(\'' + box_id + '\');"'
                    + ' style="background: #FFF url(' + this.img_path + '../images.' + box_size + '/' + box_id + image_ext + ') no-repeat center center" '
                    + 'class="' + box_id + ' openid_' + box_size + '_btn"></a>';
        }
        var x = box_size == 'small' ? -index * 24 : -index * 100;
        var y = box_size == 'small' ? -60 : 0;
        return '<a title="' + this.image_title.replace('{provider}', provider["name"]) + '" href="javascript:openid.signin(\'' + box_id + '\');"'
                + ' style="background: #FFF url(' + this.img_path + 'openid-providers-' + this.sprite + '.png); background-position: ' + x + 'px ' + y + 'px" '
                + 'class="' + box_id + ' openid_' + box_size + '_btn"></a>';
    },

    /**
     * Provider image click
     * 
     * @return {Void}
     */
    signin : function(box_id, onload) {
        var provider = providers[box_id];
        if (!provider) {
            return;
        }
        this.highlight(box_id);
        this.setCookie(box_id);
        this.provider_id = box_id;
        this.provider_url = provider['url'];
        // prompt user for input?
        if (provider['label']) {
            this.useInputBox(provider);
        } else {
            $('#openid_input_area').empty();
            if (!onload) {
                $('#openid_form').submit();
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * Sign-in button click
     * 
     * @return {Boolean}
     */
    submit : function() {
        var url = openid.provider_url;
        if (url) {
            url = url.replace('{username}', $('#openid_username').val());
            openid.setOpenIdUrl(url);
        }
        if (openid.demo) {
            alert(openid.demo_text + "\r\n" + document.getElementById(openid.input_id).value);
            return false;
        }
        if (url.indexOf("javascript:") == 0) {
            url = url.substr("javascript:".length);
            eval(url);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    },

    /**
     * @return {Void}
     */
    setOpenIdUrl : function(url) {
        var hidden = document.getElementById(this.input_id);
        if (hidden != null) {
            hidden.value = url;
        } else {
            $('#openid_form').append('<input type="hidden" id="' + this.input_id + '" name="' + this.input_id + '" value="' + url + '"/>');
        }
    },

    /**
     * @return {Void}
     */
    highlight : function(box_id) {
        // remove previous highlight.
        var highlight = $('#openid_highlight');
        if (highlight) {
            highlight.replaceWith($('#openid_highlight a')[0]);
        }
        // add new highlight.
        $('.' + box_id).wrap('<div id="openid_highlight"></div>');
    },

    setCookie : function(value) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (this.cookie_expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = this.cookie_name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=" + this.cookie_path;
    },

    readCookie : function() {
        var nameEQ = this.cookie_name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for ( var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
                c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0)
                return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    },

    /**
     * @return {Void}
     */
    useInputBox : function(provider) {
        var input_area = $('#openid_input_area');
        var html = '';
        var id = 'openid_username';
        var value = '';
        var label = provider['label'];
        var style = '';
        if (label) {
            html = '<p>' + label + '</p>';
        }
        if (provider['name'] == 'OpenID') {
            id = this.input_id;
            value = 'http://';
            style = 'background: #FFF url(' + this.img_path + 'openid-inputicon.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 50%; padding-left:18px;';
        }
        html += '<input id="' + id + '" type="text" style="' + style + '" name="' + id + '" value="' + value + '" />'
                + '<input id="openid_submit" type="submit" value="' + this.signin_text + '"/>';
        input_area.empty();
        input_area.append(html);
        $('#' + id).focus();
    },

    setDemoMode : function(demoMode) {
        this.demo = demoMode;
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

Why would it work locally but fail on the web?

Thank you.

To refine the question more.  When hosting locally with IIS Express Model.UserName is set correctly and the login in successful.  When hosted on the web (DiscountASP IIS 7.0) Model.UserName does not get set and the login fails.  The question is why?  Does this have something to do with IIS? Does it have something to do with cookies? How would I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Google issues different OpenID Claimed Identifiers to different OpenID realms.  When you log in locally your realm is likely 'localhost' but in production it's obviously different, so Google issues different OpenIDs causing you to not recognize the user.  Google is fairly unique in this respect.

I suggest you obtain your claimed ids from your production realm.

Comment: Does the production realm Claimed Identifier depend on the IP?  I will be putting the database up to be used by multiple users in different realms with most likely dynamic IPs.  I have to be able to put it up with the user and role defined once, not with each new user?  Is that a workable scheme?  Thanks, Joe

Comment: It's not based on IP address.  The realm is the string that goes into the OpenID request, and it is usually the base URL of the web site.  For example `http://www.yourserver.com/`.  As long as the realm does not change (at all! including http vs. https) the identifiers will be the same.

Comment: Will take a look at this over the weekend.

Comment: I got it to work with IE9 on Win7Ult.  I then tried it with Chrome (17.0963)and it worked.  I then tried it with FireFox (12.0) and it fails the Model.User test.                 Then on my Win XP SP3 setup IE8 times out after signing into Google never returning to the View logic.  Firefox works.  Due to other problems I haven't been able to test it in Chrome.   I need to be able to use this cross platform and browser.

Comment: To be more specific with the WinXP SP3 IE8 problem, after entering the username and password for the google login the browser is redirected to https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth.  The page is never resolved and the browser eventually times out.

Comment: Works in Safari (5.1.5) on Win7ult.  Works in Safari (5.1.2) on WinXP SP3.

Comment: This shouldn't be dependent on browser or OS.  So your goals are inline with the intention of the protocol.  My only guess is that your URLs are slightly different (capitalization, trailing slashes, etc) each time you run the test and get a different result.

Comment: When I had someone in another city log into the site using the Google OpenID, it either returned no Model.User name or the Google OpenID rather than the DB user name associated with the Google OpenID, preventing the user from being logged in.  Don't know that it can be made to work.